# Want to see whether my app has any developer alert through graph api explorer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to check whether my app has any developer alert through graph api explorer. I have my app Access Token, appid, appsecret. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

**No** you can't.

Since there's no [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) available for this.